# Add active class to wp_nav_menu

Tags: menus, navigation, walker

I'm using this code but it's not working

```
function special_nav_class($classes, $item){
    if( in_array('current-menu-item', $classes) ){
        $classes[] = 'active';
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);
```

Inspect Element:

```
<li id="menu-item-106" class="d-inline-block menu-item menu-item-type- 
post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-32 
 current_page_item menu-item-106 active"><a href="#">Something</a></li>
```

Add active class but still it doesn't change the design still the same.

Comment: The code works fine and you can see it in the Inspector. First, clean up all caches and refresh the page. Second, check your CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wont need that PHP code to style links to the current page in your nav.  WordPress adds a class (current-menu-item) by default on links to the current page.  But WordPress does not style the link for you.  That would be part of the theme. You can add a rule to the theme's CSS ( typically /wp-content/themes/your_theme/style.css ) to style the link differently. For example :

```
li.current-menu-item a {
    color: pink;
    // or whatever
}
```

Comment: Thnx for the answer.Just checked the style.css and saw that current-menu-item is nowhere.

Comment: @TestimiUEB You may want to reread my answer : "WordPress does not style the link for you" ... "You can add a rule"